Display specific product attribute description in WooCommerce single product page
I have attribute "Details" and one of the values of this attribute - "Oversize". This value have description "Please note, this model runs large. We recommend ordering a size smaller".
So, I want to get this attribute's value name and description for product and then show it on single product page.
I use:
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'my_short_desc', 16 );

function my_short_desc(){
global $product;
$detail_name = $product->get_attribute('details');
//$detail_desc = how to get it?

echo $detail_name . '<br>' . $detail_desc;
}

I don't understand, how to get value's description.
I know, that there is function term_description(), but if I use term_description($detail_name) it's don't work. I need to use value's ID, but I don't know, how to get it fast in my function.

If it's a global product attribute (taxonomy), you can use the following to display specific product attribute term name and description, in single product page:
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'display_product_attribute_short_desc', 16 );
function display_product_attribute_short_desc(){
    global $product;

    $taxonomy = 'pa_details'; // Product attribute taxonomy (always start with "pa_")
    $terms = get_the_terms($product->get_id(), $taxonomy); // Get product attributes terms

    if ( $terms ) {
        $term = current($terms); // Get the first term if many

        echo $term->name . ( $term->description ? '<br>' . $term->description : '');
    }
}

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). It should work.
